# Asus S300C is blocked by abnormal disk business

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, swap, lag

I have been using my laptop ASUS S300C through various ages. Recently I am experiencing a continuous lagging functioning and not responding windows.

It does not matter what OS I have installed (Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Linux distros), every moment the hard-drive is working hard and I barely am able to gain the cursor to write some text or perform other tasks.

The computer works but the user experience is awful, because I lose control every moment.

I checked some settings of the software I am using and the computer is no longer reaching to 100% memory usage. Furthermore, the blocking behaviour is not even related to high cpu loads.

It seems that the hard-drive is called for work every moment and it is a bottleneck. I have no issues with data transfer.

Also browsing is very difficult, tabs are sort of stuck, they  are rendered with effort, they seem to be blocked for a certain amount of time. Very often I lose wifi connection (because of the system in trouble I think).
It's not a throttling issue, I think it depends on the swap system but it is called with no reason.

What can I do to use my computer again like I used to do?

Below there is the S.M.A.R.T. tools output:

```
C:\Program Files\smartmontools\bin>smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-win8.1] (sf-6.6-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi/HGST Travelstar Z5K500
Device Model:     Hitachi HTS545050A7E380
Serial Number:    TE85423NG6MT7W
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 770c3047c
Firmware Version: GG2OA6C0
User Capacity:    500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Wed Dec 26 15:48:02 2018
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed

                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (   45) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off supp
ort.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 119) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_
FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -
       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   253   253   033    Pre-fail  Always       -
       1
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   078   078   000    Old_age   Always       -
       35041
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -
       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   067   067   000    Old_age   Always       -
       14640
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -
       3594
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       184
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   069   069   000    Old_age   Always       -
       313762
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   187   187   000    Old_age   Always       -
       32 (Min/Max 11/45)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       1
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -
       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 12 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 12 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 14219 hours (592 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 87 c1 2d 0a  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0a2dc187 = 170770823

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 01 50 87 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:39.670  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 48 86 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:39.670  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      06:45:39.670  READ LOG EXT
  60 01 40 86 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:39.293  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 38 85 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:39.292  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 11 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 14219 hours (592 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 86 c1 2d 0a  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0a2dc186 = 170770822

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 01 40 86 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:39.293  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 38 85 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:39.292  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      06:45:39.292  READ LOG EXT
  60 01 30 85 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.915  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 28 84 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.915  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 10 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 14219 hours (592 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 85 c1 2d 0a  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0a2dc185 = 170770821

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 01 30 85 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.915  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 28 84 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.915  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      06:45:38.914  READ LOG EXT
  60 01 20 84 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.537  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 18 83 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.537  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 9 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 14219 hours (592 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 84 c1 2d 0a  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0a2dc184 = 170770820

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 01 20 84 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.537  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 18 83 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.537  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      06:45:38.536  READ LOG EXT
  60 01 10 83 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.159  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 08 82 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.159  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 8 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 14219 hours (592 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 83 c1 2d 0a  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0a2dc183 = 170770819

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 01 10 83 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.159  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 08 82 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:38.159  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      06:45:38.159  READ LOG EXT
  60 01 f8 82 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:37.781  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 01 f0 81 c1 2d 40 00      06:45:37.781  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA
_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6557         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6418         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6375         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6345         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6288         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6135         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6095         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6006         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: @DavidPostill see edits